# Phonegap 3.5 Media Plugin Error on iOS "Failed to start recording using AvAudioRecorder"

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to let users record an audio file in a Phonegap app. It works well on Android, but on iOS I get the following error when the recording should start:

"Failed to start recording using AvAudioRecorder".

I use a .wav filename, I create the file first, I have followed all instructions I have found and I keep getting the error.

This is the piece of code:

```
theFileSystem.root.getFile(filename,{create:true},function(fileEntry){
    mediaFileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
    console.log('Created file ' + mediaFileURL);
    mediaRec = new Media(mediaFileURL, function(){
        //console.log('Media File created');
    }, function(err){
        alert('Error creating the media file: ' + err.message);
        console.log(mediaFileURL);
        for(k in err){
            console.log(k + ': ' + err[k]);
        }            
        stopRecordingFile();
    });
    mediaRec.startRecord();
},function(err){
    alert("Error setting audio file"); 
});
```

I see the console message 'Created file ...' so the file is successfully created. Then I get the error.

Media plugin version is 0.2.11

I don't know what else to try. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a way to resolve this?

Comment: Yes please look at my answer below, that solved the issue for me.

Comment: That does not work in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this myself.

I'll leave solution here in case it helps someone.

For iOS, this needs to be changed:

```
mediaFileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
```

to this:

```
mediaFileURL = fileEntry.fullPath;
```

Also, even though I was requesting the Persistent filesystem, iOS saved the file in the tmp folder. So to upload the file afterwards using FileTransfer, I used this to refer to the file (I tried different approaches and this was the one that worked):

```
sendFileURL = cordova.file.tempDirectory + filename;
```

Comment: You have saved this guys life >>

Answer (score 0):

following fix to the Url solved the problem for me.

```
fixFileName = mediaFiles[i].fullPath.indexOf('file://') > -1 ? mediaFiles[i].fullPath : "file://" + mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
```

Answer (score -1):

ok. this creepy error was solved.

all i did was made the file extension to uppercase, i.e.
made ".wav" to ".WAV".